Is "Bridge Sibling" an acceptable term for Half-siblings of a Half-siblings?
Is Bridge-sibling  an acceptable term for Half-sibling of a half-sibling if none of their parents are dating or married? [e.g. The Kardashian Sisters and Bruce Jenner's children, other than Kendall and Kylie if Bruce had never been their stepdad]
Are there any alternative terms?
As far as I know, step-siblings are only those who are children of a step parent. I personally feel like this should have a separate term.

Can you please show where you obtained the term "bridge sibling"? I can only find it in Urban dictionary.

That's where I found it.

Uh, is half sibling of a half sibling a quarter sibling? Why does it change if the "parents" are dating?

Half siblings share half the "blood", therefore the term but their half-siblings do not share blood among themselves so I don’t think we can call them " Quarter" siblings

If there is no blood share then there is no siblinghood.

Maybe dating doesn't count? As long as the parents are married, the partner of the parent is a step-parent. Children of the step-parent who do not share blood are step-siblings. If the marriage never happened or they get divorced, then they shouldn’t really be step-siblings anymore.

Are you saying the tenuous relationship changes from one date or failed marriage to the next?

Hmm, maybe they can't be called siblings but there should be a term to define their relationship, if they share a half-sibling and meet each other frequently.

Couldn't be any harm in generalizing with sibling except in court. Parents who adopt do not refer to their kids as real or adopted.

Using 'sister' or 'brother' is more warming than 'sibling', and these are not always used literally.
